# Is it possible to draw non continuous line chart (Line breaking chart) in sencha Ext.js?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, sencha-charts

I am going design line chart in sencha Ext.js. Can anybody tell me, Is it possible to draw non continuous line chart (Line breaking chart) in sencha Ext.js ? for reference i have attached image. Thank you [image: blue and red color line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i got answer from sencha forum, We can't do line breaking chart. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?258157-Is-it-possible-to-draw-non-continuous-line-chart-(Line-breaking-chart)-in-sencha-Ext.&p=945869#post945869